# What is the value of $\sum_{p\le x} 1/p^2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

My question is that what is the value of 
$$\sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p^2}?$$
More generally, what is the value of
$$\sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p^n}?$$ 
How can we find it?

For $\sum_{p\le x} 1/p$ the idea is to use the summation $\sum_{p\le x}\ln p/p$ and Abel's summation formula. Actually, can we find any expression for something like my question?
When I use Abel's summation formula for $\sum_{p≤x}1/p$ and $\sum_{p≤x}\ln(p)/p$ some hard integrals appear.

Would you please help me? 
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185080/partial-summation-of-a-harmonic-prime-square-series-prime-zeta-functions

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99007/rate-of-convergence-of-series-of-squared-prime-reciprocals.

Comment: Might be useful: [Prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function)

Comment: This sum converges to a finite number, but there is no nice closed form for it. Its decimal expansion is given here: https://oeis.org/A085548

Comment: With $p$ you're talking about prime numbers, right? That's my first instinct, plus there's the (prime-numbers) tag, but still, it wouldn't hurt to say so more explicitly.

Comment: I contend this isn't a duplicate, because this question asks about $\sum 1/p^n$, not just $\sum 1/p^2$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared

Answer (score 3):

You probably wont be able to find a closed form representation for these sums in terms of functions you would consider simple or elementary. However if $\Re(n)>1$ and we define the following constant:

$$C_n=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)\ln(\zeta(nk))}{k}$$

Then you can rewrite your sum as:

$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^n}=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^n}-\sum_{p>x}\frac{1}{p^n}=C_n+\frac{\pi(x)}{x^n}-n\int_{x}^\infty \frac{\pi(t)}{t^{n+1}} dt$$

Which if we assume the truth of RH would give us that:

$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p^n}=C_n+\frac{\text{Li}(x)}{x^n}-n\int_{x}^\infty\frac{\text{Li}(t)}{t^{n+1}}dt+O(\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{n-1/2}})$$