# No closed form for $\sum_{n\in P} \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, closed-form

I think that I can say with a fair amount of assurance that $$\sum_{n\in \mathcal P} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ has no closed form (assuming that $\mathcal P$ represents the full set of primes)

I currently know the following:

a) The sum converges at $ 0.45224742\dots$

b) The definition of a closed from expression is that you can express the constant with the following:

- addition, multiplication, subtraction, and division
- raising a number to a power that exists (Includes reciprocals, roots, powers, and powers to fractional exponents)
- known constants such as $\pi,e, \gamma, \phi \cdots$ and no others
- trigonometric functions and their inverses ($\sin,\text{arccsc}, \cot, \text{arcsec}\cdots\text{\etc.}$)
- hyperbolic trig functions and their inverses ($\text{arccosh},\text{tanh},\text{arccoth}$)
- You may **not** use anything that involves limits. A few off limits :) might be limits, derivatives, integrals, infinite sums, infinite products, and so on.

c) I know, at least, that the number is irrational. The irrationality of this concept [in part] inspired this question.

The reason I think that there is no closed form is due to the randomness of primes and that often times even random sums have no closed form. But really, I am not looking for whether or not this has a closed form, but a proof that there exists no closed form. Go as complicated as necessary to solve. Thanks for any help.

I realize that the a proof of the closed form is often extremely difficult, and even unknown for even the simplest of constants ($\gamma$ and $\zeta(3)$). I did know of the difficulty of a proof like this before asking this question. The reason I thought it might be easier was due to how random the distribution of primes were. (Remember we are trying to prove that there is **no** closed form not the opposite.)

PS: As a high school student, could you please namedrop the names of theorems please in your proof so I could learn more?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by a "known constant".

Comment: @pre-kidney any number that is so "known" that it gets it's own symbol.

Comment: If you want a mathematical proof, you'll need to specify a mathematical definition.

Comment: You are probably right.  But wouldn't your thoughts expressed there imply that $$\prod_{n \in P}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ also has no closed form?

Comment: @pre-kidney OK, sure. ONLY use $\pi, \gamma, e$

Comment: And that product is $6/\pi^2$.

Comment: @GEdgar Shit, I misread what you wrote. Sorry

Comment: @pre-kidney Its kinda rude to dissect the small stuff and ignore the question. Which you are obviously doing.

Comment: Proving that there is no closed form for some expression can be extremely difficult. No one knows, for example, whether there is a closed form for $\zeta(3)=\sum n^{-3}$, or for Euler's $\gamma$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson One can see why I would be interested in this question, yes?

Comment: Is it even known if the number is trancendental?

Comment: @Winther I heard from a few sources that the constant was in fact transcendental

Comment: @NormalHuman How does this not have to do with prime-zeta? $\zeta (2)=$ the named constant in the question.

Comment: I'm not saying that it doesn't. I'm saying there doesn't need to be a tag for that.

Comment: @NormalHuman True, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: This post seems a bit related: [What is the value of $\sum_{p\le x} 1/p^2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107115/what-is-the-value-of-sum-p-le-x-1-p2) There is also a [post on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared) about this sum. At the moment it has one asnwer, which contains a few references.

Comment: Now posted to MO (with no link from either site to the other), http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223064/proof-that-no-closed-form-exists-for-sum-n-in-mathcalp-frac1n2

Comment: Cross-posting is generally frowned upon. But if you decide to do it, you should definitely [read this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088). (And maybe some other posts on meta about [meta-tag:cross-posting].)

Comment: Probably doesn't help, but food for thought maybe? $1 + \zeta(2)\sum_{n\in \mathcal P} \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\omega(n)}{n^2}$ 

Where $\omega(n)$ is the multiplicity of $n$, the number of distinct prime divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is equal to $P(2)$, where $P(n)$ denotes the prime zeta function defined as

$$
P(n)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{p^n}.
$$

No closed-form expression is known for any values of the prime zeta function.

> c) I know, at least, that the number is irrational.

The irrationality of the prime zeta function at any positive integer $n\geq2$ is unknown. A proof of your statement would immediately gain you considerable fame.